# How to swap ODBC connections

Tags: database, odbc, informix

I have 2 Informix databases running in parallel in a network. One is the primary server database and another one is the secondary server database. From the client node (a SCADA application), by default, I need to connect the primary database. If the primary is not active then I need to connect the secondary database. How do I switch between primary and secondary using ODBC connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably look to the Connection Manager — [`oncmsm`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=utilities-oncmsm-utility) — which is designed to handle failing over between replicas.  Your application would connect to the Connection Manager with a single handle, and the Connection Manager would route activity to the primary unless it is unavailable.

If you don't use the Connection Manager, the mechanics of switching between the two connections is simple enough.  You have the two connection handles available, and you use a third variable `current_connection` which initially points at the primary handle.  When you detect that the primary is unavailable, you change `current_connection` to point to the secondary handle.  The tricky part here is detecting when the primary is unavailable.  You'd probably need some sort of timeout on each operation, and the ability to retry the last statement after switching.  That gets intricate — as does detecting when to switch back to the primary after it has recovered.  This is the sort of stuff the Connection Manager handles automatically.